# Arduino webserver POST receive varriables

Tags: web-server

I have been learning lower level data reading on internet communication 
As a part of bigger project I am testing web interface.
So far I could get main website displayed and by seeing the web-address read the data from GET request. 
As I intend to send codes I wish to use POST method.

I am Trying to make this as standalone class for mine future projects, so I am only sending the class method itself. (Latter it would take websites content as a string, but for now input variables are yet to be implemented)
I am using esp8266, but would prefer to avoid esp8266 specific libraries as I wish it to eventually run on its realtek equivalent.
The code:

```
uint8_t Stranky::Stav(String obsahStranky, uint8_t obnovovat){
    WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    char vstupRiadok[150]={'\0'};
    uint8_t i=0;
    bool currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        vstupRiadok[i]=c;
        if(c=='\n' || i>=149) {
            Serial.println(vstupRiadok);
            //------------Extract variables here--------
            for(uint8_t j=0; j<149; j++) {
                //Serial.print(vstupRiadok[j]);
                vstupRiadok[j]='\0';
            }
            i=0;
        } else i++;
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
            Serial.println("Sending page");
            client.println(ohlasSa(1,1));
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          // send a standard http response header
            client.println("<html><head> <meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body>");
            client.println("<h1> Nic nove</h1>");
            client.println("<form method='POST'>");
            client.println("Name:<input type=\"text\" id=\"Name\" name=\"Name\"/><br>\nSurname:<input type=\"text\" id=\"Surname\" name=\"Surname\"><br>\n<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/><input   type='reset'/>  </form> </body>");
            client.println("</html>");
          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        } else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);

    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Prehliadač dpojený");
  }
}
```

This results in Browser code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head> <meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>
<h1> Nic nove</h1>
<form method='POST'>
   Name:<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name"/><br>
   Surname<input type="text" id="Surname" name="Surname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><input type='reset'/>  </form> </body>
</html>
```

When I send any data over the form it does not get received  and only receive these:

```
WS:ac
:ref 1
WS:av
:ref 2
:ur 2
:rn 469
POST / HTTP/1.1

Host: 192.168.43.209

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: sk,cs;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.2

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Referer: http://192.168.43.209/

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length: 25

Connection: keep-alive

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1



Sending page
```

No post, or Cookie variables that I could extract

I am far from home and too short of data to be installing more software like wire-shark over phones network sharing

Comment: I found that I have to decode a json object, but how do I get it from received data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on codebreakers code I have been able to combine it into working one
The problem was on a fact that communication starts with header variables, then empty line, then body containing the variables
First get the connection: and create base variables

```
uint8_t Stranky::Stav(){
    WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    bool currentLineIsBlank = 0;
    bool body=0;             // Helps seeing if this is still header
    bool finished=0;         // To know if to terminate connection
    uint8_t i = 0;           // To prevent iterator from resetting to 0
    char fullLine[81]={'\0'};  // buffer for input character to line
    // char *pch;

    Serial.print("User connected\n");
    while (client.connected()) {
        while (client.available()) {
            bool linEnd=0;          // When to deal with line (print it)
```

Get one incoming character:

```
            char c = client.read();
```

Now deal with new line character first
 
If the last line was empty That would mean: Header is finished and moving to the body of the incoming data
 If not change currentLineIsBlank (until new line gets its first character)

```
            if(c=='\n') {
                if(currentLineIsBlank) {
                    if(!body) body=1;
                    currentLineIsBlank=0;
                } else {
                    Serial. print("/");
                    currentLineIsBlank=1;
                    linEnd=1;
                }
```

Now lets deal with any other character then new line:

```
            } else {
                currentLineIsBlank=0;   //If it has a character then its not empty
                fullLine[i]=c;
                i++;                //Move to the next letter
            }
```

Make sure that our array doesn't overflow

```
            if(i>=81) linEnd=1;
```

Now we know what is happening we can take some action after the buffer line is finished

if we are at the body stage, but we havent "finised" sending code

```
            if(linEnd){ 
                if(body && !finished) {
                    finished=1;          // Finishing sending page
                    Serial.printf(F("Variables:\n\t"));
```

Start extracting characters from body of the incoming data.
In a simple form like ours POST variables are on a last line, so we will just keep rewriting the line

```
                    uint8_t k=0;
                    while (client.available()) {
                        fullLine[k]=client.read();
                        Serial.printf(F("%c"),fullLine[k]);
                        if(k<80) k++;
                        if(fullLine[k]=='\n') {        
                            k=0;
                            Serial.println();
                        }
                    }
                    // Here you can extract variables as shown in codebreakers' answer
```

Finaly send then websites html code:

```
                    Serial.print("Sending page\n");
                    client.println(heatheRoutine()); //I have extra routine to inject heather so I do not have to write it every time I write a page
                    client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
                    // send a standard http response header
                    client.println("<html><head> <meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body>");
                    client.println("<h1>Fill the form now !!!</h1>");
                    client.println("<form method='POST'>");
                    client.println("Meno:<input type=\"text\" id=\"Name\" name=\"Name\"/><br>\nPriezvisko:<input type=\"text\" id=\"Surname\" name=\"Surname\"><br>\n<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/><input    type='reset'/>  </form> </body>");
                    /*Serial.printf(F("Page source send\n"));*/
                    client.println("</html>\n");
                    break;
                }
```

If we are not dealing with the body yet:

```
                currentLineIsBlank=1;
                for(uint8_t j=0; j<i; j++) { //Print the last line
                    Serial.print(fullLine[j]);
                    fullLine[j]='/0';     //restore default values To prevent characters leaking into next line
                }
                Serial.println();
                i=0;    //Since we are on an end of a line we are starting from first position in a buffer
            }
        }
```

If we have finished what we have wanted we need to get out of communication loop

```
        if(finished) {
            Serial.printf(F("Ending\n"));
            break;
        }
    }
```

And close the connection:

```
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);

    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("browser disconnected");
  }
}
```

Complete code:

```
uint8_t Stranky::Stav(){
    WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    bool currentLineIsBlank = 0;
    bool body=0;             // Helps seeing if this is still header
    bool finished=0;         // To know if to terminate connection
    uint8_t i = 0;           // To prevent iterator from resetting to 0
    char fullLine[81]={'\0'};  // buffer for input character to line
    // char *pch;

    Serial.print("User connected\n");
    while (client.connected()) {
        while (client.available()) {
            bool linEnd=0;          // When to deal with line (print it)
            char c = client.read();
            if(c=='\n') {
                if(currentLineIsBlank) {
                    if(!body) body=1;
                    currentLineIsBlank=0;
                } else {
                    Serial. print("/");
                    currentLineIsBlank=1;
                    linEnd=1;
                }
            } else {
                currentLineIsBlank=0;   //If it has a character then its not empty
                fullLine[i]=c;
                i++;                //Move to the next letter
            }
            if(i>=81) linEnd=1;
            if(linEnd){ 
                if(body && !finished) {
                    finished=1;          // Finishing sending page
                    Serial.printf(F("Variables:\n\t"));
                    uint8_t k=0;
                    while (client.available()) {
                        riadok[k]=client.read();
                        Serial.printf(F("%c"),riadok[k]);
                        if(k<80) k++;
                        if(riadok[k]=='\n') {
                            k=0;
                            Serial.println();
                        }
                    }
                    // Here you can extract variables as shown in codebreakers' answer


                    Serial.print("Sending page\n");
                    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
                    client.println("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
                    client.println("Connection: close\r\n");
                    client.println();
                    client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
                    client.println("<html><head> <meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body>");
                    client.println("<h1>Fill the form now !!!</h1>");
                    client.println("<form method='POST'>");
                    client.println("Meno:<input type=\"text\" id=\"Name\" name=\"Name\"/><br>\nPriezvisko:<input type=\"text\" id=\"Surname\" name=\"Surname\"><br>\n<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/><input    type='reset'/>  </form> </body>");
                    /*Serial.printf(F("Page source send\n"));*/
                    client.println("</html>\n");
                    break;
                }
                currentLineIsBlank=1;
                for(uint8_t j=0; j<i; j++) { //Print the last line
                    Serial.print(fullLine[j]);
                    fullLine[j]='/0';     //restore default values To prevent characters leaking into next line
                }
                Serial.println();
                i=0;    //Since we are on an end of a line we are starting from first position in a buffer
            }
        }
        if(finished) {
            Serial.printf(F("Ending\n"));
            break;
        }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);

    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("browser disconnected");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your definition of

```
String vstupRiadok
```

it should not be

```
String vstupRiadok="                                      "; //80 blanks
```

I would replace it with a decent sized fixed char anyway

```
char vstupRiadok[81] = {'\0'};
```

if you create an empty line or other text do not forget to write the end terminator `'\0'` and make sure the char array is +1 the size for the longest string totake

As String class is a problem on its own as an Arduino class.

The HTML code generated has a missing

```
<head> <meta charset    ="utf-8"></head>
```

error in the dev-tools. Aside from that whats the server code running on the Arduino,its not given. The class creates a html page, but at least in FF75 it tries to call server.ip\odpoved - so there has to be some js or Arduino code to decode this route there are no params attached from the form.

**EDIT**An extraction routine would look like:

```
bool currentLineIsBlank = true;
bool currentLineIsGet = true;
uint8_t tCount = 0;
char tBuf[64];
uint8_t n=0;
uint8_t s=0;
char *pch;

Serial.print("Client request: ");

 while (client.connected()) {
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();

    if (currentLineIsGet && tCount < 63) {
      tBuf[tCount] = c;
      tCount++;
      tBuf[tCount] = 0;
    }

    if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
      Serial.println(tBuf);
      // retrieve the POST data
      Serial.print("POST data: ");
      while (client.available()) Serial.write(client.read());
      Serial.println();

      pch = strtok(tBuf, "?");

      while (pch != NULL) {
        if (strncmp(pch, "Name=", 5) == 0) {
          pch = pch+6;
          char Name [24] = {'\0'};
          while(pch != '&'){
             char Name [n] = pch;
             n++;
           }
          char Name [n+1] = {'\0'};
          Serial.print("Name="); Serial.println(Name);
        }

        if (strncmp(pch, "Surname=", 8) == 0) {
          pch=pch+9;
          char Surname[24] = {'\0'};
          while(pch != '\r') {   // check if your response has that after the content or if its '\0'
             char Surname [s] = pch;
             s++;
           }
          char Surname [s+1] = {'\0'};
          Serial.print("Surname="); Serial.println(Surname);
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL, "& ");
      }
  // here the Sending response part starts
```

You do not need a JSON parser for this just get the post request

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106650/discussion-on-answer-by-codebreaker007-arduino-webserver-post-receive-varriables).